# intellij: 'sbt' is not recognized

Tags: scala, intellij-idea, sbt, sbt-plugin

I have installed sbt plugin in intellij, but whne I try to run some sbt command, it is not recognized.

```
>sbt clean compile
'sbt' is not recognized as an internal or external command,
operable program or batch file.
```

Shouldn't sbt plugin take care of this?

Comment: Do you have "Scala" plugin installed?

Comment: yes, its installed.

Comment: where do you run set command? In terminal window?